# Is there really an official "Microsoft unlock tool" for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I can read here:

http://www.chevronwp7.com/post/12809851723/chevronwp7-labs-faq

"This seems to affect **both** the **Microsoft unlock tool** and **ours**."

I thought chevronwp7 was the only one, then why are they mentionning "both" which makes think there is another one ?

What is it compared to chevron and where can I find it? Is there any difference between the two if I don't need to publish to market but just use on my own device?

Answer (score 1):

They are referring to the App Hub unlock tool that ships with the SDK (and requires an App Hub subscription). There are no other unlock options other than an App Hub subscription and ChevronWP7.

Comment: Is there any difference between the two if I don't need to publish to publish to market but just use on my own device ?

Comment: Yes, the official version costs $90 USD more :)